Add OwnerTx Failed
I am trying to add an owner to my deployed safe wallet. I am using Safe4337Pack. Even though my Safe is being deployed I am getting:
Error: Safe is not deployed

This is my code:
const safe4337 = await Safe4337Pack.init({
    provider: "https://eth-sepolia.public.blastapi.io",
    signer: OWNER_2_PRIVATE_KEY,
    bundlerUrl:
      "https://api.pimlico.io/v1/sepolia/rpc?apikey=API_KEY
    options: {
      owners: [wallet.address, wallet2.address, OWNER_3_ADDRESS],
      threshold: 2,
      // safeAddress: "0x62cd1d6f28CF7d22c10f9740C0B7eFF165Cea8a7",
    },
  });

const addOwner = await safe4337.protocolKit.createAddOwnerTx({
    ownerAddress: OWNER_4_ADDRESS,
    threshold: threshold + 1,
  });


  const tx = await safe4337.protocolKit.executeTransaction(addOwner);

I even double-checked whether my safe account:
 const address = await safe4337.protocolKit.getAddress();
  const isDeployed = await safe4337.protocolKit.isSafeDeployed();
 const owners = await safe4337.protocolKit.getOwners();

output:
 owners: [
    '0x6B127667C864862B05acCa75fF066BE7Bd77fBA5',
    '0x7Cb6cAfa1fB1eAf283C185ce57296866b3b6829B',
    '0x8c893bCa192f4eE9e7B86c936B1507a52fFA8378'
  ],
isDeployed : true,
address: 0xE4AaE32a17FCD6E703a5AfC8Da57CA7FBBD1288F


Thanks for your question.
The code you posted looks correct, but I don't have the full context. So here are some ideas.

The address in the init function comment is different from the address of your Safe. Both Safes are deployed on Sepolia, though. But maybe this is a hint to double-check your configuration.
If you don't require the 4337 functionalities, I suggest using the Safe{Core} Protocol Kit directly.

So maybe you should try to use the Safe{Core} Protocol Kit directly, initialize the Safe with its address, and try again to execute the addOwner transaction. Let me know if you encounter any issues.
If it works, please mark your question as answered.
